# LFTP Reconnect infinite loop

Tags: reconnect, lftp

When I try to connect to the host that is dwon I get the following message:

```
cd `sftp://example.com/tmp' [Delaying before reconnect: 30]
```

After each attempt delay sis increasing. I found the following command that should help me:

```
repeat -d 10  -c 1
```

which should delay by only 10 seconds (instead of default 30) and repeat th ecommand only once.

But still I get Delaying reconnect in endless loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ok found it:

```
lftp -e "set net:max-retries 2;set net:reconnect-interval-base 5;set net:reconnect-interval-multiplier 1 ;mirror  -v --just-print '/tmp/md1/' '/tmp/m2'" sftp://example.com
```